# Compiling a Java applet with libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I am trying to develop a Java applet for scientific purposes. I am working in Eclipse, on Ubuntu 11.04; since I needed some additional features, I included the libraries "flanagan.jar", "jcommons.jar" and "jfreechart.jar". Now, when I run the applet from inside Eclipse everything goes fine. When I try to do so OUTSIDE of Eclipse, however, not quite. To say a few examples:

1) if I try to run it by embedding it into an HTML file with  or  tags, the applet fails and I get an error because the definitions for the classes taken from the libraries are missing, even though I placed them in the same folder and used the proper `archive` value to tell the browser where to look for them;

2) if I try to compile the applet with javac, by inserting:

```
javac -classpath sourcefile.java library1.jar library2.jar
```

I get an error saying that the class names for the .jar files `are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested`.

3) I can find no way to produce a single output .jar file embedding all the required library files. I also think it would be neat if I could avoid embedding the entire libraries (they weigh something around ~4 MB) and actually use only the .class files I really need. I don't know how to do however. Could you give me some suggestion on how to do one of the three things above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your jar list immediately after the `-classpath` argument using a colon `:` demilited list:

```
javac -classpath library1.jar:library2.jar sourcefile.java
```

You could use Eclipse to produce a single output jar by using:

```
Export...->Java->Runnable JAR File->Next->Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR.
```

Then you can either jar up the content of the new jar file sub-folder or use:

```
javac -classpath sub_folder/*.jar sourcefile.java
```

Comment: Thank you! After compiling it by hand the thing works. I suppose with Eclipse one should keep the original structure of the folders containing the libraries. Too bad. And I didn't know about the colon thing.

Comment: To answer your edit: I already tried the "Runnable JAR File" thing, and it doesn't work, because it requires a Launch Configuration, i.e., a "main" method. This is an Applet, so... no main whatsoever.

Comment: You could create an application from your applet using this [example](http://www.woodger.ca/jv_appst.htm)

Comment: Yes, but I'm not very interested into that right now... I need it to be an applet, and to know how to run it from inside a browser. It's something that has to end up on a website. Thanks again anyway, I think it should work fine from now on, I'll just compile stuff by hand and put all the libraries in! I suppose if I wanted to I could cherrypick only the classes I need and put them into a new .jar file, but that's just too much work. Either I'll find a way to script it, or I'll just go with the memory-consuming solution.

Comment: This is pretty easy to automate with [ant](http://ant.apache.org/).  You'll want to take a close look at the [jar task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html)